# Merge multiple ics calendar files into one file

Tags: command-line, calendar

From the command line, how can I merge multiple `.ics` calendar files in to one `.ics` calendar file?

Answer (score 3):

I used this script:

```
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR" >> merge;
for file in *.ics; do 
cat "$file" | sed -e '$d' $1 | sed -e '1,/VEVENT/{/VEVENT/p;d;}' $2  >> merge; 
done
mv merge merge.ics
echo "END:VCALENDAR" >> merge.ics;
```

Comment: This leads to the sed error `sed: 1: "1,/VEVENT/{/VEVENT/p;d}
": extra characters at the end of d command`

Comment: Are you on Linux? As I understood sed has problems on BSD and Mac systems. If so - try "sed -i''.

Comment: Correct, I am on Mac. Now the error is `sed: -I or -i cannot be used with stdin`.

Comment: Solved with a lengthy php script.

Comment: @PatrikNovák : The fix for your script is only one additional semicolon. Because it's such a small change, the system won't let me edit it for you. **Here's what I was trying to add for the EDIT summary:** _The complaints about the script failing were due to a missing semicolon after "d" within the second sed command. The code for the second sed command can be easily written as_ 
`sed -e '1,/VEVENT/{/VEVENT/p;d;}' $2` 
I tested and confirmed it works on both Mac and Linux.
Cheers! :)

Comment: Concatenating `.ics` files (esp. when just extracting the `VEVENT` blocks) is a partial solution, especially if the source `.ics` files are invitations (`text/calendar` attachments). `METHOD:CANCEL` will not be handled, so the resulting calendar will contain events that had been canceled. `UID` deduplication is not done, so it will have duplicate events unless the consuming calendar program deduplicates them. Most importantly, each `VCALENDAR` can have its own `VTIMEZONE` information, which is discarded here completely. Beware.